# How to permit a nested reference in a form_with helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails app with a nested association (`Shop` > `Products`). Products also `belongs_to` another model `Collections`. This is intended to be a loose association, such that I can perform a filtered query on Products but not require double nesting. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the Collection reference in the form permitted through the controller to the model.

[Note: Collections are a predetermined set of choices I insert for each shop `after_create`. There is no separate form to create these. The only choice for the user is to select a collection for the product they're creating.]

All of these classes use slugs with `to_param`.

```
  resources :shops do
    resources :products
  end
```

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :assignments
  has_many :roles, through: :assignments
  has_many :collections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
  has_one_attached :main_image

  before_save :set_slug
  after_create :add_collections
```

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :collection
```

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  has_many :products
```

I seem to be hitting a hurdle permitting params in my controller. Originally I tried passing `:collection` as a standard form field, but a friend recommended the use of `fields_for` instead. Here's my current form structure.

```
<%= form_with(model: [@shop, @product]) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :collection %>
    <%= f.fields_for :collection do |cf| %>
      <%= cf.select :id, @shop.collections.pluck(:name).map {|n| [n.capitalize, n] } %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

The `create` method uses the Shop association.

```
  def create
    @product = @shop.products.new(product_params)

    if @product.save
      redirect_to @product, notice: "Product was successfully created."
    else
      flash.now[:errors] = @product.errors.full_messages
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Finally, here is the private method to permit the Product params on create.

```
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :main_image, collection: [:id])
  end
```

On form submit, I'm seeing this error. I've tried different approaches to permitting the nested reference, but I just keep hitting different brick walls. This *feels* like the right approach, but I'm stumped on how to proceed. Any ideas?

```
09:31:21 web.1  | ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Collection(#185640) expected, got {"id"=>"gear"} which is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#160300)):
09:31:21 web.1  |
09:31:21 web.1  | app/controllers/products_controller.rb:18:in `create'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not about the strong params stuff, this is about the fact that when you do `...products.new(product_params)` you're sending in a hash with one of the elements as `collection: { "id" => "gear" }` which means Rails is then trying to set the `collection` attribute to that hash, ie. `the_new_product.collection = { "id" => "gear" }` which is failing because that's a `belongs_to :collection` and so is expecting to receive a `Collection` object not a `Hash`, eg. in normal code you'd write something like `Product.new( other: stuff, collection: Collection.new(id: "gear"))`

The way to handle nested attributes like this is to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), which creates getters/setters to handle the attributes and automatically create the objects for you.

Note, you'll need to update your `product_params` to expect the new `collection_attributes` param.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had received similar feedback from someone else. I've implemented nested_attributes but I'm still hitting similar issues as before. My updated notes are available as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/obfuscurity/dbd8d8b5974c12339efc06076ec5f7ff).

Comment: Feel free to update your question above.